# Apache equivalent of IIS application roots

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, mod-rewrite, documentroot

Someone just set up a directory for me on an Apache server where I will put my PHP application. This directory has an external path of `192.168.1.5/app` and points to `/home/test/app`.

My application references its files by means of **URLs like `/img/logo.png`**, rather than `../img/logo.png` or something similar. The problem I'm experiencing with this is that these URLs now point to `192.168.1.5/img/logo.png` instead of `192.168.1.5/app/img/logo.png`.

In IIS, to fix something like this, I would declare the app directory as an application, which would **set the root URL to that directory**. **How do I do something similar in Apache** (using this method or something else entirely)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to change the `DocumentRoot` for this application. Since you're accessing it via IP (instead of hostname), I'm guessing that you're using the default apache vhost. If so, change the `DocumentRoot` in your `httpd.conf` file to point to `/home/test/app`, restart apache, and you should be all set.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure whether I can get access to `httpd.conf`. Is there a way to do this through `.htaccess`?

Comment: No, you cannot change the DocumentRoot via `.htaccess`.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Sorry, I just have one last question: since this isn't the only application on the server, should I look up `DocumentRoot` or `VirtualDocumentRoot`? In other words, which is more appropriate here?

Comment: If you have more than one application, then you need to change the `DocumentRoot` in whatever `VirtualHost` that is serving this application.

Answer (score 0):

Mod rewrite. There are so many different configurations that I can't post any specific ones here. But you could use dreamweaver to update all links. Are you trying to get /test/app/images/stuff? What directory are the images in? And it is a good thing you are in relative path mode. That saves much time. Try putting the images folder inside test folder.